# regular expression for the filter

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to check the validity of the filter expression

for example the user enter to textBox expression "F117 AND F118".It will be correct! but..
user can enter expression that would not be correct. for example: "F117 F118" , "F117,F118" etc

correct syntax only "asd" or "asd AND asgdfg"

If expressions are not valid/correct then should shown exception

please tell me how to do this with regular expression

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes. recursion ) but it's code very bad

Comment: You can still post that, just to show what you have tried.  And give a few concrete examples, that might help us understand what you want (or even better, what you need).

Comment: yep. this is very vague without some more code or context.

Comment: sorry. I have edited question.now it will be better for the understand

Comment: always only 1 or two?  what about `ask AND fsa AND qwer`?  Or, `(ask AND fsa) OR resa`

Comment: ask AND fsa AND qwer     => correct.

correct only AND. without ,/()& ....etc

Comment: If you are clarifying the requirement of your question, is is nice to edit the original question so that people don't have to read the comments to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(( AND [a-z0-9]+)+)?$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not terribly specific, but you will want something like this:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^\w+( AND \w+)*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if(!r.IsMatch(input))
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Meaning:

```
^            #Start of string.
\w+          #Some word characters.
( AND \w+)   #A group containing the word AND followed by some word characters.
*            #That previous group can repeat zero or more times.
$            #End of string.
```

Comment: very good but "f111 and f112 and f113" will not work.

Forgot to clarify.
Expression "asd AND  gdfg AND fghfgh" should be correct

Comment: Ok, I have changed it to be case insensitive.  The repetition of AND is already taken care of by the *.

Comment: @BuhBuh You missed the `*` out of the first copy of the regex.

Comment: @RoadieRich, oh jeeze, you're right. Sorry, I was sure I wrote *.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Without a better definition of the problem:

```
(\S*)(\s(?:AND)\s(\S*))?
```

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/gBzxzgUtLa) to play with it.

Capture group 1 will have your first term and group 3 will have your second (if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but this is what I came up with.

```
var s = "f123 AND f234";
if(/^([a-z A-Z]{1}[0-9]+)$|(([a-z A-Z]{1}[0-9]+) AND ([a-z A-Z]{1}[0-9]+))$/.test(s))
alert("Eurica!");
```

where the test method checks if the string you passed is correct according to the regex.

```
^: starts with 

a-z A-Z : small letters and capital letters i.e A or a ...

0-9: digits 

+: 1 or more ... so till now we have f123 or F12345 or F133453

|: or

$: ends with
```